# How can I center this picture vertically and horizontally?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a box that is a variable width and height. In my example I want to center the picture halfway down the box. What is the best way to approach this with just CSS? I'd rather not use any JavaScript if I dont have to.

Example at: http://codepen.io/wesbos/pen/Ehour

my HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200">
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.box {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the DIV a `table-cell` and then use `vertical-align` property:

```
.box {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;    
  display: table-cell;
}

img{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: `display: inline-block` isn't necessary is it? It's default is `inline` and this appears to work?

Comment: No, but I've added it to point out that the image shouldn't be `block`

Comment: Thanks so much, we were just showing how helpful stack overflow is @ThisIsHackerYou and you proved my point! Thanks a ton, we all learned about display:table-cell; today! :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is just by making the image as background for the div centered and with no-repeat value and without the need to use text-align attribute, here is how:

HTML

```
<div class="box">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:url(http://placekitten.com/200/200) no-repeat center center;
}
```

You can replace the link in url() with the image you want either on the local machine or a link for the image on a web server like the one above